# .NET WebService Sending Large XML File

Tags: .net, web-services, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a list of objects List that I need to send over a web service.  The list contains about 37,000 Objects.  This translates to about a 125 MB XML File if I serialized it to XML.

I think by default web services communicate via serialized XML.  This leads me to believe I am actually sending 125MB file each time.  In binary format this would only be about 5MB.  Is there a way to make the Web Service call in binary format to avoid the large bandwidth hit?

Comment: What is your origin and destination capabilities?  Can each end gzip and ungzip?

Comment: Webservice is likely not the best solution here, provide some more infomation about the service consumer.

Comment: I am dealing with a consultant that expects the data in a format of an array of objects: Object[].  This prevents me from compressing or changing the data in any way.  I can probably get them to change it but I just want to make sure there is no way to force the web service to serialize in binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use WCF for your webservice? If so: WCF support [streaming large data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx) across the wire.

If you have any chance of compression that data on the server side to 5 MB in a ZIP or something, you could definitely stream that across to your client.

You would have something like this as your WCF service contract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://yourservice.com/streaming/2009/12")]
interface IYourStreamingService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Stream GetListOfObjects(int id);
}
```

You can define methods that either take or return data as a "Stream", and the client can then open that stream like a `FileStream` or a `MemoryStream`, and the data will be streamed across the wire in chunks, so you won't need to allocate the whole data in memory before sending it to the client.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

- You could serialize to a binary array.
- Then translate that array to a string.
- Put that string in a structure, and send it over.
- Then on the other side, convert the byte string array, back to a normal byte array.
- Then re-serialize it into the object you need.